# GLSL Support on VMware Player

Tags: ubuntu, glsl, vmware, vmware-player, mesa

I managed to install OpenGL driver on a VMware ubuntu guest using the methods described [here](http://www.mesa3d.org/vmware-guest.html).

I'm wondering with this method will provide GLSL support under this VM, and if yes, where can I get the include files that has the OpenGL GLSL-related functions declarations such as glCreateShader(), or glShaderSource() and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I made more tests and it turned out that, yes, GLSL is supported. And the way I got the functions include was by building and adding the GLEW library to my project.